# Limited singleton lifetime determined by another object

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

This may be something to be solved with Autofac nested scopes, but I have not been able to make enough of the documentation to figure it out myself.

I think what I am looking for is like a per-HTTP-request singleton, but the place of the request is taken by the lifetime of another object.

There is a class `SubSystem`, of which a new instance is created (resolved from the container, potentially through a factory class) every time new data is loaded into the application (the old data and `SubSystem` instance are discarded).

Then there are classes `SomeFeature`, implementing `IFeature`, and `SomeService`, implementing `ISomeService`.

`SubSystem` has dependencies on both `IFeature` and `IService`, while `SomeFeature` takes a dependency on `IService`. So the object graph looks like this:

```
SubSystem
└> SomeService : IService     <─┐
└> SomeFeature : IFeature       ├─── same instance
   └> SomeService : IService  <─┘
```

`IFeature` is only required in one place, so a transient registration is fine here. `IService` on the other hand must be resolved to the same instance for all dependencies within *this* subgraph, but when new data is loaded and a new `SubSystem` instance is created, its subgraph must get its own new "per-request singleton" `IService` instance.

The reason for discarding the instances is that they cache information from the loaded data for performance reasons, which will not be valid anymore when new data is loaded. I am currently using real singleton instances that have their local state reset via an event raised in the `SubSystem` constructor, but that is clearly a less than optimal solution.

As I said, I'd like this to work like `InstancePerHttpRequest()`, but as "instance per `SubSystem`".

Is there a way to achieve this using the Autofac API?

Comment: Would `IFeature` or `IService` ever be singletons outside of the `SubSystem` dependency?  Does `SubSystem` just need new instances when it's being refreshed (or currently, refreshing itself)?

Comment: Outside the context of `SubSystem`, anything about `IFeature` and `IService` is currently "undefined"; right now, they only exist to support this part of the application. And yes, new instances are only needed on creation of a new `SubSystem` instance, because `SubSystem`'s lifetime is tied to the same "data work session" as the values that those components may cache.

Comment: This seems like a problem of premature optimization (caching). Your solution shouldn't be concerned with how underlying dependencies function, whether there is a cache there or not.  Craft the solution without the cache first, then build caching as a separate concern.

Comment: I don't understand. I am not building "my solution"; I have a working application with all the parts in place, but I want to improve the infrastructure. (And `SubSystem` currently has to know that the state of its dependencies need to be reset via that event, and I want to get rid of that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option I think you're looking for is:

```
.InstancePerOwned<SubSystem>()
```

If you only consume `SubSystem` in one place, just take a dependency on `Owned<SubSystem>` at that point, **and make sure** you `Dispose()` the `Owned<T>` in the consuming component's `Dispose()` method.

For something a bit more transparent, assuming you can create `ISubSystem` to go with `SubSystem` you can do this:

```
builder.RegisterType<SubSystem>()
  .InstancePerOwned<SubSystem>();

builder.RegisterType<SubSystemGraph>()
  .As<ISubSystem>()
  // Appropriate sharing here...
  ;
```

Where `SubSystemGraph` is:

```
class SubSystemGraph: ISubSystem, IDisposable
{
  readonly Owned<SubSystem> _root;

  public SubSystemGraph(Owned<SubSystem> root)
  {
    _root = root;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    _root.Dispose();
  }

  // Methods of ISubSystem delegate to _root.Value

  public void Foo()
  {
    _root.Value.Foo();
  }
}
```

(This could be packaged up into a nicer interface on Autofac but it's not all that common in practice.)

Comment: Thanks Nick; I only just got around to trying this in the project, and it does what I need. It requires being a bit more exact about a few Autofac related things, but that's not a bad thing. Incidentally, I already have something very similar to the `SubSystemGraph` class in place, so the visibility of the `Owned<T>` is constrained to that. What irritated me a little is that disposing the `Owned<T>` instance does not dispose its `.Value`; why is that?

Comment: Interesting - AFAIK `Owned<T>` should `Dispose()` the `T`, this might be one for the Autofac group, if you have a repro? Cheers!

Comment: I found the reason - as the `Value` instance is resolved from the `Owned<T>`'s lifetime scope, disposing the scope should also take care of disposing the instance. In my case, that was registered as `ExternallyOwned()` from my previous solution, so it evaded disposing through the lifetime scope. All sorted now. :-)